# Cannot choose between the following configurations of project

Tags: android

I checked out the source code from a repository and when I compiled the source code, I got the following error message:

```
Cannot choose between the following configurations of project :android-pdf-viewer:
  - debugApiElements
  - debugRuntimeElements
  - releaseApiElements
  - releaseRuntimeElements
All of them match the consumer attributes:
  - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
      - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
  - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
      - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
  - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
      - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
  - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
      - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
      - Found org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
```

Comment: I just tried to upgrade the root and the dependencies projects from API version 23 to 26.

Comment: Can you add code from `build.gradle`  app module?